# How to determine click location coordinates in iphone app view class

Tags: iphone, uiview, viewcontroller, coordinate

i'm trying to make a connect four iphone app. I have made my own custom UIView class, which is where the game is played. However, I am trying to use the touchesMoved, touchesEnded, etc. methods to retrieve data based on where the user clicked (so i know which column they are trying to put a piece into). How can i get this information from the viewController class to my UIview class?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and potentially override `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to ignore touches in views that I may have overlaid. It does depend on your view hierarchy really.